# Can't unlock disks encrypted with Mavericks after upgrade to Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac, encryption

I have 2 (microSD) disks encrypted under OS X Mavericks. I didn't use FileVault 2, I just used normal "Encrypted Logical Partition" from Finder with a complex password which was not saved in Keychain. I wrote my password physically on a paper.

Normally when I connect my disks to my Mac with Mavericks the unlock screen pops up, I enter my password and then the drive is unlocked and everything is OK :).

Yesterday I installed the Yosemite OS 10.10 beta. Everything is fine except when I connect my previously encrypted disks. The pop up shakes with "no" even when my password is correct!

I tried to fix the permissions with the command line, and then when trying to unlock my disk from the command line it ended up with this message:

```
-69749: Unable to unlock the Core Storage volume
```

I checked and repaired the disk from disk utilities and a green message came with everything is OK.

Comment: For SEO, apparently the following is shown when using Terminal: `-69749: Unable to unlock the Core Storage volume`

Comment: ...are you the same person as the author of [this post on the Apple community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6466336)...? (Needs beta access to view, I guess.) Then why not provide the same details here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. I ended up having to boot into the internet recovery mode and do a fresh install of Yosemite. I had to wipe my hard disk clean using Disk Utility first.

I've noticed that Yosemite now has the option to use your Apple ID login info to login to your computer much like Windows 8 does with your online Microsoft account that's used for things like buying apps from the app store.

I'm suspecting your issue has something to do with this. The internet recovery mode on my Mac had an option to reset my disk encryption password using my Apple ID, but since I had never chosen to use my Apple ID account to log in to my computer before this didn't work.

My advice for anyone that has installed their original version of Mac OS X to an encrypted volume would be to decrypt it first. You can always encrypt it again after installing the Yosemite beta.